# Wordpress enqueuing scripts in post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

this is a noobish question but I really tried several options, none of them seemed to work. I have a plugin that is a slideshow with some posts, it works just fine on homepage (index). It uses jquery 1.4.2 and a javascript file. The idea is that when I go inside a post, the javascript file is not loaded, imported (inspecting the sources using chrome's webdev I can see the plugin's style.css but not the javascript file).

I tried several options, apparently the jquery used by wordpress is a bit too old and I need 1.4.2.

I tried registering the 1.4.2 jquery (I will refer as jq), and then enqueuing the script file depending on the new jq, in plugin's php file, also enqueuing the style.css. I also tried including the next code inside functions.php, still not working:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'load_slideshow_scripts');

function load_slideshow_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('slideshow-jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.4.2', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('slideshow-js', plugins_url('contest-slideshow/script.js'), array('slideshow-jquery'), '1.0', false);
    wp_enqueue_style('slideshow-css', plugins_url('contest-slideshow/styles.css'));
}
```

I also tried enqueuing the js files in a function that I hooked to init, still no success. I also tried simply enqueuing these files along with the other scripts loaded by default by the theme in functions.php.

The real problem is that the javascript file is not loaded and the slideshow is not working while in single post, otherwise it works

Answer (score 0):

If it's really a jQuery related problem, you should deregister it first. Try out with this:

```
function modify_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', false, '1.11.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

This piece of code has to be inside the functions.php of your theme. I used the last 1.x jQuery version but edit it if you need/prefer another one.

Good luck!